# Changing colors on turtle graphics on key press

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was writing a code on turtle and I got stuck in changing colors "onkey", using colorsys (hsv_to_rgb) with everything set but hue, I declared a variable for it. It was going all well till launch, it only changes once. Here's the code:

```
from turtle import *
from colorsys import *

pencolor('blue')
pensize(2)
bgcolor('black')
default_size = 0
h = 0


def move_up():
    sety(ycor() + 50)


def move_left():
    setx(xcor() - 50)


def move_right():
    setx(xcor() + 50)


def move_down():
    sety(ycor() - 50)


def change_color():
    n = 0.1
    c = hsv_to_rgb((h+n), 1, 1)
    color(c)


def call_movement():
    onkey(move_up, 'Up')
    onkey(move_left, "Left")
    onkey(move_right, "Right")
    onkey(move_down, "Down")
    listen()


def color_change():
    onkey(change_color, "+")
    listen()


call_movement()
color_change()

done()
```

I tried using while and set limit to h = 1, it works but not how I want it, it cycles but I want it to go once store the changes on the variable for the next time I use the key, creating a sort of a partial cycle or so

Answer (score 1):

You are not ever setting the value of `h`, so it never changes.

Fix:

```
n = 0.1
...
def change_color():
    global h
    h += n
    c = hsv_to_rgb(h, 1, 1)
    color(c)
```